# About generic currying in swift

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming, currying

I am stuck with the following problem:

> Question 1 - Generic currying
>   Create a protocol named `Worker` containing a function called `perform`, which takes in a function and returns a function; `perform` must have a default implementation.
>   The function passed as a parameter should be named `work`, and takes as an argument an instance of the type conforming to the protocol and returns a generic type T. The output function is () -> T

```
struct Person {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

protocol Worker {
    func perform<A,T>(work: @escaping (A) -> (T)) -> () -> T
}

extension  Person: Worker {
    func perform<A, T>(work: @escaping (A) -> (T)) -> () -> T {
        return //execution of the function work
    }
}
```

The result of this should be something like this:

```
let person = Person(name: "Bob", age: 3)
let work = person.perform(work: {return "\(person.name) is working"})
print(type(of: work)) // () -> String
print(work()) // Bob is working
```

I am thinking that I have to return the execution of the work function passed as the parameter to my protocol function perform.

Am I thinking right? If I am, how could I do that?

I have already read about currying and generics, but I still can't figure this out.

**EDIT 1:**

I fixed the part about the default implementation, but I still can't figure it out how to return that closure.

```
struct Person: Worker {
    var name: String
    var age: Int
}

protocol Worker {
    func perform<A,T>(work: (A) -> (T)) -> () -> T
}

extension  Worker {
    func perform<A,T>(work: @escaping (A) -> T) -> () -> T {
        return {}
    }
}
```

I went back to my textbook and they give me the following example about currying a function:

```
func curry<A, B, C>(_ f: @escaping (A, B) -> C) -> (A) -> (B) -> C {
    return { x in { y in f(x, y) } }
}
```

So in my mind the return of my function should be:

1. A closure with no arguments ()
2. With a closure inside that receives an argument that is passed to work.

Like this:

```
return {() in {x in work(x)}}
```

The compiler gives me the following error:

```
Cannot convert return expression of type '() -> (A) -> T' to return type '() -> T'
```

I can't understand why that happens because the inner closure

```
{x in work(x)}
```

in my mind should return an value of type T, since it is the execution of the function work, but instead it returns an (A) -> T.

What am I missing?

Comment: First, I'm going to recommend going back to your text book for the answer to your homework.  The key in the question is "default implementation"  You'll also want to consider how to return a closure.

Comment: @DavidBerry thanks, I'm going to check that!

Comment: @DavidBerry I edited my question with my findings, but I couldn't  figure it out the part about returning a closure. I explain where my mind is in the question edit.

Answer (score 1):

> The function passed as a parameter should be named `work`, and takes as an argument an instance of the type conforming to the protocol

Swift makes “the type conforming to the protocol” available as `Self`. So `work`'s argument should be `Self`, not `A`. You don't need the `A` type at all.

```
protocol Worker {
    func perform<T>(work: @escaping (Self) -> T) -> () -> T
}
```

Given that signature, how can we write a default implementation?

- We have to return a function that returns a `T`.
- We can only make a `T` by calling `work`.
- We have to pass a `Self` to `work`.
- The only `Self` available is `self`.

So this is the only reasonable default implementation:

```
extension Worker {
    func perform<T>(work: @escaping (Self) -> T) -> () -> T {
        return { work(self) }
    }
}
```